# Failure to run postgresql on Mac (after reboot)

Tags: linux, macos, postgresql, permissions, postgresql-9.2

Whatever I did I couldn't start postgresql 9.2 on Mac 10.9.3 again after reboot.

```
$ initdb -D /usr/local/var/postgres
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "alex".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.UTF-8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

initdb: directory "/usr/local/var/postgres" exists but is not empty
If you want to create a new database system, either remove or empty
the directory "/usr/local/var/postgres" or run initdb
with an argument other than "/usr/local/var/postgres"
```

I decided I should create another directory in it. So I created data directory there and ran initdb again:

```
$ initdb -D /usr/local/var/postgres/data
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "alex".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.UTF-8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /usr/local/var/postgres/data ... initdb: 
  could not change permissions of directory "/usr/local/var/postgres/data": 
   Operation not permitted
```

I tried to change the permissions but didn't figure out what were the right ones. Here is what I have:

```
$ ls -ald /usr/local/var/postgres
drwxr-xr-x  22 _postgres  staff  748 Jun 13 17:26 /usr/local/var/postgres

ls -ald /usr/local/var/postgres/data
drwxr-xr-x  2 _postgres  staff  68 Jun 13 17:26 /usr/local/var/postgres/data


$ ls -al /usr/local/var/postgres
total 96
drwxr-xr-x  22 _postgres  staff        748 Jun 13 17:26 .
drwx------   3 alex       admin        102 Jun  1 15:08 ..
-rw-------   1 _postgres  _postgres      4 Jun  1 15:08 PG_VERSION
drwx------   6 _postgres  _postgres    204 Jun  2 11:40 base
drwxr-xr-x   2 _postgres  staff         68 Jun 13 17:26 data
drwx------  42 _postgres  _postgres   1428 Jun  2 14:18 global
drwx------   3 _postgres  _postgres    102 Jun  1 15:08 pg_clog
-rw-------   1 _postgres  _postgres   4465 Jun  2 10:58 pg_hba.conf
-rw-------   1 _postgres  _postgres   1636 Jun  1 15:08 pg_ident.conf
drwx------   4 _postgres  _postgres    136 Jun  1 15:08 pg_multixact
drwx------   3 _postgres  _postgres    102 Jun  1 18:24 pg_notify
drwx------   2 _postgres  _postgres     68 Jun  1 15:08 pg_serial
drwx------   2 _postgres  _postgres     68 Jun  1 15:08 pg_snapshots
drwx------   7 _postgres  _postgres    238 Jun  2 21:23 pg_stat
drwx------   2 _postgres  _postgres     68 Jun  2 21:23 pg_stat_tmp
drwx------   3 _postgres  _postgres    102 Jun  1 15:08 pg_subtrans
drwx------   2 _postgres  _postgres     68 Jun  1 15:08 pg_tblspc
drwx------   2 _postgres  _postgres     68 Jun  1 15:08 pg_twophase
drwx------   4 _postgres  _postgres    136 Jun  1 15:08 pg_xlog
-rw-------   1 _postgres  _postgres  20571 Jun  1 15:08 postgresql.conf
-rw-------   1 _postgres  _postgres     79 Jun  1 18:24 postmaster.opts
-rw-------   1 _postgres  _postgres   1482 Jun  2 21:23 server.log
```

What should I do next? I'm out of ideas. The only guess is that it is related to a file or folder permissions.

Comment: `initdb` does not start postgres, it creates a data directory from scratch. When it already exists, this fails as a protection against wiping out the previous data.

Comment: When postgres fails to start it emits error message(s) telling why. You want to read these messages.

Answer (score 0):

Two step process:

1. Go to your web-browser and search for "postgresql permissions data directory" - look down the list for the page from the official manuals (it's the top one for me).
2. Read the [page from the official manuals](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/creating-cluster.html) and follow the instructions.

Presumably it's complaining that it "could not change permissions" because you aren't running this as user "_postgres". Note - it's normally user "postgres". I don't know if the name-change is something you've done or something common on Mac installations.

Oh - and I can't see why this is tagged "linux"

Comment: let me check that. it's linux because it's not mac ox specific issue.

Comment: On linux you'd probably be using something package-based. For example, Debian has its multiple-installed-version wrapper `pg-createcluster`.

Comment: This page in the docs solves it http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/creating-cluster.html